# Android: ScrollView center content?

Tags: android, xml, android-viewpager, scrollview

I have a ViewPager that shows some lines of text on each slide. Some are short like the first image below, and some are long like the second image. I have implemented ScrollView so that the longer slides have scrollbars, and that works fine. The problem is, I can no longer vertically center the other slides that don't need ScrollView.

How would I center the text vertically in the first image below, that is wrapped in a ScrollView? Possible to set something like `if this fits in the view, don't use ScrollView`?

Thanks!

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                  android:background="@drawable/border">

            <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/SCROLLER_ID"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_view1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Hello"
            android:textColor="#323232"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_weight="1.0" />

        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ScrolllView`'s height is set to `wrap_content`. It means that when the text is short (e.g. 1 line) the `ScrollView` does not take all the screen, so the text can't be centered.

Set the `android:layout_height` property of the `ScrollView` to `match_parent`.

BTW, you should use `match_parent` instead of `fill_parent` as this last one is now deprecated.